# Replace javascript onmouseover with jQuery only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that displays a dynamic amount of "orders" and I have a button to "view" and another button to "print". To display the specific OrderNumber I'm using a javascript function triggered by onmouseover and a jQuery ajax function to change the button text, make a database entry, and then view or print another page. The problem is the order is viewed or printed MULTIPLE times from onmouseover. How can use only jQuery and call the specfic OrderNumber? Here is the code I'm using now:

This code is repeated for each order:

```
<div class="console_orders_details">
<input type="button" value="View" 
id="vieworder'.$row[orderid].'" onmouseover="vieworder('.$row[orderid].');">
</div>
```

Here is the function to view the order:

```
function vieworder(id){
            $(function(){
                $('#vieworder' + id).click(function(){
                    var orderid = id;
                    var dataString = 'orderid='+ orderid; //string passed to url
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        url: "includes/ajax/console-view.php", //url of php script
                        dataType: 'html', //json is return type from php script
                        data: dataString, //dataString is the string passed to the url
                        success: function(result) 
                        {
                            window.open("print.php?view=1&orderid="+id+"");

                            $('#vieworder' + orderid + ':input[type="button"]').attr("value", "Viewed!").fadeIn(400);

                         }
                    });
                })
            });
        }
```

I'm assuming I need to eliminate the "vieworder" function and use a pure jQuery function. However, I don't know how to send over the order "id", which is why I used javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target all elements with an ID that starts with `vieworder`, and then store the row ID as a data attribute :

```
<div class="console_orders_details">
    <input type="button" value="View" id="vieworder'.$row[orderid].'" data-id="'.$row[orderid].'">
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(function(){
    $('[id^="vieworder"]').on('click', function(){
        var orderid = $(this).data('id'),
            btn     = $('input[type="button"]', this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/ajax/console-view.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {orderid : orderid}
        }).done(function(result) {
            window.open("print.php?view=1&orderid="+orderid+"");
            btn.val("Viewed!").fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I will try this and see what happens.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I did have to re-use my "Viewed!" function from above to get that to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't have a dynamic id that you have to parse, and don't have an event handler in your html:

```
<div class="console_orders_details">
   <input type="button" value="View" class="vieworder" data-id="$row[orderid]">
</div>
```

Next, create an event handler for just what you want to do. .one() will set an event handler to fire only once:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".console_orders_details").one("mouseover", ".vieworder" function(){
        var dataString = "orderid=" + $(this).data("id"); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/ajax/console-view.php", //url of php script
            dataType: 'html', //json is return type from php script
            data: dataString, //dataString is the string passed to the url
            success: function(result) {
                window.open("print.php?view=1&" + dataString);
                $(this).val("Viewed!"); 
             }
        });
    });
});
```

If you want this to work onclick, then just change the mouseover to click. Also, fadeIn doesn't work on values. Here is a fiddle that has the basics: http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/EnK2M/1/

Comment: I'm looking for the most efficient way to handle what I'm trying to do. I'm pretty new at this so I'm not sure wat you mean having a click handler in the vieworder function is rather odd means. How do you recommend writing this and possibly structuring the CSS properly? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It is hard to be certain what you are trying to do. Your question states you want to fire this onmouseover and you only want it to happen once, but then in the onmouseover function, you define an onclick handler for the same element. So, what I think is going to happen is your user will mouse over the button, and nothing will happen the first time, then they click on it, and it will do what you want. And then every time they click it is will do it again. It may also happen over and over onmouse over, since your click handler is basically acting as a closure.

Comment: @XanderNGCC So, I guess the big question is, do you want this to happen onmouseover or onclick? and do you really only want to happen once?

I will revise my answer above to match my assumptions that you want this to happen once onmouseover.

Comment: I want it to happen on click. But for some reason I couldn't get it to fire onclick, only when I sent it with an onmouseover would the onclick fire. And only happen ONCE.

Comment: Just change mouseover to click then in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Your onmouseover event is probably being fired many times, resulting in your problem. This might help to stop unwanted extra calls, by ignoring them unless the previous one has completed.

```
var activeRequests = {}; // global

function vieworder(id){
  if (activeRequests[id]) { return; }
  activeRequests[id] = true;
  $(function(){
    $('#vieworder' + id).click(function(){
      var orderid = id;
      var dataString = 'orderid='+ orderid; //string passed to url
      $.ajax
      ({
        url: "includes/ajax/console-view.php", //url of php script
        dataType: 'html', //json is return type from php script
        data: dataString, //dataString is the string passed to the url
        success: function(result) {
          delete activeRequests[id];
          window.open("print.php?view=1&orderid="+id+"");
          $('#vieworder' + orderid + ':input[type="button"]').attr("value", "Viewed!").fadeIn(400);
        }
      });
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! or should I restructure my CSS and use a purely jQuery approach? I'm looking for the best, most efficient way to write this and follow best practices.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. If your suggesting removing CSS and replacing it with JavaScript that generates CSS then no, why give the browser more to do. Try to find a way to use less ajax (when is not required, not just less in general) if your requesting the same data as a previous request then what's wrong with the previous result?